# VW Jetta MK2 cluster lights

Tags: electrical

When I switch on my the lights when the car is running the cluster lights goes off and increase the brightness the rev counter goes down and it lights still don't light up but when the car is off the cluster light comes on well, what causes this?

Comment: Corrected your use of all caps, often seen as shouting at us.

Comment: Can you measure battery V vs RPM and symptom? Cell s.g.? Alternator diode test?

Comment: Thank you , no I don;t know how to do the test, if you can tell me how to i will be able to do it.